# where() does not process parameters as expected in sqlalchemy

Tags: python, sql, sqlite, sqlalchemy

```
table = engine.getFTable();
dBtable = table; 
query = select([dBtable.c.id]).where( dBtable.c.FName == 'F1' );
print(query);
```

This gets the right table but for some reason the query constructed is not the what one would expect. The following is the query constructed

```
SELECT "FList".id 
FROM "FList" 
WHERE "FList"."FName" = ?
```

instead of

```
SELECT "FList".id 
FROM "FList" 
WHERE "FList"."FName" = 'F1'
```

Answer (score 1):

SQLAlchemy creates [parameterized SQL queries](https://blog.codinghorror.com/give-me-parameterized-sql-or-give-me-death/) whenever possible.

That means the `?` in your queries `WHERE` clause is just a placeholder that will be filled in with the actual data (`'F1'`) when executing the query (the parameters are then  *bound* to the query).

The exact [syntax of the bound parameter placeholder](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0249/#paramstyle) depends on the SQL dialect you're using (PostgreSQL, MySQL, ...). Some use `?`, some support named parameters like `:user_id`.

You can see the parameters that will be filled in by compiling that query object, and showing it's parameters:

```
>>> query = select([table.c.userid]).where(table.c.userid == 'lukas.graf')
>>> print query
SELECT users.userid
FROM users
WHERE users.userid = :userid_1            <---- bind parameter placeholder

>>> compiled = query.compile()
>>> print compiled.params
{u'userid_1': 'lukas.graf'}
```

The [SQLAlchemy documentation](http://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/latest/faq/sqlexpressions.html#how-do-i-render-sql-expressions-as-strings-possibly-with-bound-parameters-inlined) explains how to render SQL expressions as strings, if you need to debug them:

```
>>> from sqlalchemy.dialects import postgresql
>>>
>>> query = select([table.c.userid]).where(table.c.userid == 'lukas.graf')
>>> compiled = query.compile(dialect=postgresql.dialect(), compile_kwargs={"literal_binds": True})
>>> print compiled
SELECT users.userid
FROM users
WHERE users.userid = 'lukas.graf'
```

Also note the passage from that documentation:

> The above forms will render the SQL statement as it is passed to the
>   Python DBAPI, which includes that bound parameters are not rendered
>   inline. SQLAlchemy normally does not stringify bound parameters, as
>   this is handled appropriately by the Python DBAPI, not to mention
>   bypassing bound parameters is probably the most widely exploited
>   security hole in modern web applications.

Meaning, the parameterized query and, separately, the parameters to bind to it, will be passed along to the Python DBAPI (the DB "driver", if you will) like this, because that's the most performant and secure way to do things. You can visualize the query with inlined parameters as shown above, but that's not really what's going over the wire.

---

Instead, if you're debugging your queries, you should much rather use the [`echo=True` parameter for the engine](http://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/latest/core/engines.html): This will conveniently log both the parameterized queries as they're executed, *and* their bound parameters.